# Create and Update Model with 2 related Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this models

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accountings
  has_many :commodities, through: :accountings
end

class Accounting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :commodity
end

class Commodity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accountings
end
```

My book form is:

```
<%= form_for(book) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: book %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :commodity_ids %>
  <%= f.collection_select :commodity_ids, Commodity.all, :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
  <br />
  <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

At the BooksController:

```
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    if @book.save
      redirect_to @book
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    if @book.update_attributes(book_params)
      redirect_to @book
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:name, commodity_ids: [])
    end
```

All this works fine. And `Accounting` records are added and deleted when `commodity_ids` are updated. (1)

Now I need to add a new model: `Company`, since `Book` and `Commodity` are shared by all companies, `Accounting` must belongs to `company`, and also not shared at all the system. And `Accounting` becomes:

```
class Accounting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :commodity
  belongs_to :company
end
```

The `Company` model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accountings
end
```

`Accounting` is more than a relation between commodities and books (and companies), it represent a business model too.

The constraint here is: When a new `Commodity` is added to a `Book`, then a new `Accounting` must be created for **each** `Company`. (2)

I did try to relate `Book` with `companies`, through `accountings`. But, it does not work. Even it does not represent the business model and Book don't care about Company, I think Book is a good candidate for link the models. (3)

Now I'm thinking add a new model `BookCommodity`, that relate books and commodities through this model, and on save this new model generate the `Accounting` records needed for all `companies`. (4)

Before add this fifth model I want ask you if there are a better way to manage this stuff?

**Edited**

At Github you can find a [demo_finance](https://github.com/alejandrobabio/demo_finance/commits/with_companies) project, with only the code of this post. It has 4 branchs:

- **master**: The first version, before adding the Company model, of course it works fine. (1)
- **with_companies**: The **master** branch with the Company model, and the constraints needed at Accounting model. (2) This is a starting point for any changes.
- **first_attempt**: The **with_companies** branch with the attempt: (3). It does not work.
- **second_attempt**: The **with_companies** branch with the attempt: (4). It works. It has a callback on create for Accounting creation, but it will need more callbacks for commodity deletion at Books#update. I'm not completely satisfied with this approach.

The key task here is add or remove commodities to a book, and get accountings updated, just like it works at version (1) (master branch).

**Edit #2**

I tried to do this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accountings
  has_many :commodity_companies, through: :accountings
  has_many :commodities, through: :commodity_companies
end
```

but it doesn't work. On update it raises:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly
  Cannot modify association 'Book#commodities' because it goes through more than one other association.
```

I also try to do this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accountings do
    def build(attributes = {}, &block)
      Company.all.each do |company|
        @association.build(attributes.merge(company_id: company.id), &block)
      end
    end
  end
  has_many :commodities, through: :accountings
end
```

But, this build action is not called on update books with `commodity_ids=`.

Comment: why not before_update and if comidity_ids changed then create new accounting for each (new) company

Comment: what do you mean by "new Accounting must be created for each Company” ? Give an example of a database with some existing records and how it should look like after you relate a Book to a Commodity

Comment: It's a good starting point @huanson. Just remember that now Book has many commodities through accountings.

Comment: @Gus This is an Accounting system for a Firm, which has many Companies, also it is a low number (now it start with 4, and it is expected to grow up to 8). I will prepare the data you are asking for.

Comment: i feel, that this is a easy solution, but i really struggle to get your models into my brain. did you wrote all the tests to do? maybe then its more clear what should happen exactly when

Comment: @huanson I'm are aware that is hard to figure out how all this works. That's why, I simplified the code to make you see only the relevant part that helps to find an answer. Yes, I have wrote test, I have 10 thousand of app lines of code and 13 thousand of specs. I'm pretty sure it will not help. On the other hand, as I said, I'll add some more information, but I must to prepare it.

Comment: 10k LoC in a rails app? hopefully including views and assets. otherwise i'fell "sorry"

Comment: well, if thats the project which is linked at github, i dont see 13.000 LoC there -.-

Comment: @huanson: The original project it's a private one, which runs at customer's intranet. I built the github project in order to get and test the answers for this question. If you give me instructions to make it work, I will translate to the real app.

Comment: okidoki. hope you get it fixed

Comment: What are each of the models doing? To provide model advice we need to know what the reality we're trying to replicate is.

Comment: It's an accounting system, which is shared by all the Companies of a Holding. Book is the accounting structure. Accounting represent each isolated balance, and Commodity is the unity of this balance (could be a currency or any commodity). Anyway, the right answer was selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question:**

I did not select this answer as the right one yet. Because, although it works, I think there could be better answers, which would deserve the bounty.

I made it work overwriting the method `commodity_ids=`, also is needed to add `dependent: :destroy` option to accountings, and scope `-> {uniq}` to commodities.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accountings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :commodities, ->{ uniq }, through: :accountings

  def commodity_ids=(ids)
    self.accountings = Commodity.where(id: ids).map do |commodity|
      Company.all.map do |company|
        accountings.find_by(company_id: company.id, commodity_id: commodity.id) ||
          accountings.build(company: company, commodity: commodity)
      end
    end.flatten
  end

  def commodities=(records)
    self.commodity_ids = records.map(&:id)
  end
end

class Commodity < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Accounting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :commodity
  belongs_to :company

  def to_s
    "#{book.name} - #{company.name} - #{commodity.name}"
  end
end
```

Running at the console from scratch:

```
~/ (main) > Book.create name: 'Book 1'
=> #<Book id: 1, name: "Book 1", created_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:23", updated_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:23">
~/ (main) > Commodity.create name: 'Commodity 1'
=> #<Commodity id: 1, name: "Commodity 1", created_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:37", updated_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:37">
~/ (main) > Commodity.create name: 'Commodity 2'
=> #<Commodity id: 2, name: "Commodity 2", created_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:40", updated_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:40">
~/ (main) > Commodity.create name: 'Commodity 3'
=> #<Commodity id: 3, name: "Commodity 3", created_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:42", updated_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:42">
~/ (main) > Company.create name: 'Company 1'
=> #<Company id: 1, name: "Company 1", created_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:51", updated_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:51">
~/ (main) > Company.create name: 'Company 2'
=> #<Company id: 2, name: "Company 2", created_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:54", updated_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:54">
~/ (main) > bb = Book.first
=> #<Book id: 1, name: "Book 1", created_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:23", updated_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:23">
~/ (main) > bb.commodity_ids = ['', nil, 1, '3']
=> [
    [0] "",
    [1] nil,
    [2] 1,
    [3] "3"
]
~/ (main) > bb.save
=> true
~/ (main) > bb.reload
=> #<Book id: 1, name: "Book 1", created_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:23", updated_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:23">
~/ (main) > bb.accountings.map(&:to_s)
=> [
    [0] "Book 1 - Company 1 - Commodity 1",
    [1] "Book 1 - Company 2 - Commodity 1",
    [2] "Book 1 - Company 1 - Commodity 3",
    [3] "Book 1 - Company 2 - Commodity 3"
]
~/ (main) > bb.commodities.map(&:name)
=> [
    [0] "Commodity 1",
    [1] "Commodity 3"
]
~/ (main) > bb.commodity_ids = ['']
=> [
    [0] ""
]
~/ (main) > bb.save
=> true
~/ (main) > bb.reload
=> #<Book id: 1, name: "Book 1", created_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:23", updated_at: "2015-09-30 11:47:23">
~/ (main) > bb.commodities.map(&:name)
=> []
~/ (main) > bb.accountings.map(&:to_s)
=> []
~/ (main) >
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only a solution. After, I've learned deeply your questions. I'd say you have to add all companies in your book form as multy-select options. I knew perhaps it will make it out of your idea now but you have to follow about rails flow. You've said that you want to update commodities through accounting based on companies and then you want to update data automatically but your code don't provide to do these.

*OPTION 1*

This is the suggestion:

**Controller**

Add new strong parameter

```
def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:name, commodity_ids: [], company_ids: [])
end
```

**Model**

You need to revised some associations

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accountings
  has_many :commodities, through: :accountings
  has_many :companies, through: :accountings
end

class Accounting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :commodity
  belongs_to :company
end

class Commodity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accountings
  has_many :companies, through: :accountings
  has_many :books, through: :accountings
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accountings
  has_many :books through: :accountings
  has_many :commodites through: :accountings
end
```

**View**

You can select all companies as selected in order to user don't need to select options (optional)

```
<%= form_for(book) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: book %>
  <%= f.label :company_ids %>
  <%= f.collection_select :company_ids, Company.all, :id, :name, {:selected: Company.all.map(&:id)}, {multiple: true} %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :commodity_ids %>
  <%= f.collection_select :commodity_ids, Commodity.all, :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
  <br />
  <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

As addition, try not to create `BookCommodity` to create `Accounting` because `BookCommodity` is equal to `Accounting`

*OPTION 2*

For another option if you want to not show in your form you can add in your model in before_save callback. This is only

```
before_save :set_companies

def set_companies
  self.company_ids = Company.all.map(&:id)
end
```

**Conclusion:**

Those are having pros and cons. In first options, user can select the company but the user need to choose the company first. Last one, the user don't choose the companies but he will get difficulties when the user want to update the company of the book or commodity. As always, I would prefer to you to use the first one way because the user will easy to edit. That's all. I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But, it does not work as expected. I tried this, and you can find at [github](https://github.com/alejandrobabio/demo_finance/tree/first_answer) branch "first_answer". It store a new accounting for each company with null commodity, and others new accounting records for each commodity with null company. I did test only option 1, but option 2 is pretty the same setting companies at model instead at form.

Comment: Okay. Option 2 is not complete because you have to revised your model as option 1 above because there are no associations in your current model.

Comment: At github link added before, you will find branches 'first_answer' and 'first_answer_option2', where I test your two options. Both behaves equal. You can check if I did a mistake following your indications, and, of course test yourself.

Comment: I've just checked first_answer that you did right. I think you have to do this tutorial https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect application for the [acts_as_tenant](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant) gem.  I have this gem running in a production application and it is an excellent solution.  You can basically take your original working solution and replicate it for each company within your system just by using this gem.  Each company's data would be isolated to its own system within a single database.

The documentation is excellent but I would be happy to answer specific questions about the implementation.  I combine this gem with Sorcery and Rolify for authentication and authorization, but that's up to you.  I can have many companies on one image.  In your case, your firm could easily switch to different companies but you could allow individual companies access to only their data.

It's an elegant but simple solution to such a complex issue.

Comment: If you want to discuss in some detail, we should set up a chat.

Comment: Thank you for answer, and offering help. I evaluated the acts_as_tenant gem, and it did not fit with my requirements. We need two visions of the organization chart, vertical (by Companies) and horizontal for management. I've chosen "Pundit", using its two main features: scopes and authorization. After that, I could change from 'users & admins' to 'roles' smoothly.

Comment: @AlejandroBabio  Certainly pundit for authorization is fine.  That was beside my point, however.  acts_as_tenant solves your data design problems.  Thanks.